# facebook profile img redirect not loading image

Tags: html, facebook

This must be an easy one, but can't get to solve it:

I'm getting an url from facebook login api, like this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/10152374498960753/picture?width=150&amp;height=150
```

if I store that and put it in a  it doesn't load

```
<img alt="64x64" class="avatar media-object pull-left" src="http://graph.facebook.com/10152374498960753/picture?width=150&amp;height=150">
```

because the above url is actually redirecting to another url. Shouldn't the browser deal with the redirect by it self? anyways, How can I get the image to lad??

Thanks!

Comment: First of all dogs shouldnt smoke. It is working for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/SSKx7/

Comment: You may have an add blocker stopping the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

It is working!

This one is working fine

```
http://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture?width=170&amp;height=170
```

Perhaps, the problem is regarding your ID because this user data request

```
http://graph.facebook.com/10152374498960753
```

alone gives a **Bad Request** status.

Make sure you have the right ID and double-check the privacy status of the user.